# Django/Flask: почему нельзя без nginx в production?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django, flask

Везде по всем учебникам написано: в production используйте nginч, а не сервер предоставляемый фреймворком.

Какие есть главные подводные камни, прежде всего влияющие на безопасность?

дикая многопоточность, масштабирование и производительность в моем случае не интересует, т.к. для конкретного приложения используется схема "один пользователь -- один сервер"

Comment: "дикая многопоточность, масштабирование и производительность" - ну вот поэтому в учебниках так и пишут :)

Comment: Самое главное - НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ не использовать встроенный runserver, потому что его делают только для разработки и о безопасности никто особо не заботится. А нижеупомянутые gunicorn и uwsgi, может, можно ставить и без nginx

Answer (score 2):

1. Сервера, предоставляемые Django/Flask работают в один поток. Боюсь что при таком подходе загрузка страниц будет очень медленной, или даже будут рваться соединения.
2. Перед Django/Flask обычно ставят "сервер приложений" -- gunicorn или uwsgi. Их вполне себе можно выставить наружу. Они в общем-то много чего умеют, в том числе делать терминацию ssl.
3. Nginx разрабатывается давно, его используют много крупных компаний, и уж будьте уверены -- его рассмотрели и рассматривают со всех сторон, причем куда пристальнее чем встроенные сервера django/flask.

**UPD**

- dev сервера django и flask оказывается могут работать в многопоточном режиме. Но нужно понимать что это потоки в python, в котором gil. Если вы в потоке делаете в основном системные вызовы (запросы в базу, чтение файлов, запросы на сторонние ресурсы), то возможно все будет работать более менее нормально для небольшого количества запросов. Касаемо aiohttp/sanic/другой асинхронный веб-сервер - пока в рамках запроса вы делаете обращения в бд/сторонние ресурсы, то все будет ок.

Comment: А встроенный в aiohttp, как по первому пункту?

Comment: @Lecron aiohttp.web - полноценный сервер, перед который не обязательно ставить что-либо ещё. К тому же он асинхронный, поэтому способен одним инстансом обрабатывать одновременно десять тысяч соединений. Но всё же [статику раздавать](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#static-file-handling) лучше Nginx'ом.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых - сервер, предоставляемый фреймовиком, предназначен для разработки. А для работы в интернете на продакшене есть Apache или Nginx. По большому счету - без разницы. Многопоточность - gunicorn.

Можете сроутить на сервере входящие запросы с tcp 80 порт на tcp 8000. Ну это назвать продакшеном трудно. Пойдет конечно - на каком нибудь внутреофисном проекте, для отдела бухгалтерии. Но отсутствие многопоточности - это 1 запрос за раз. Если этого достаточно для Ваших целей - тогда можете свободно использовать.

Comment: Встроенный сервер реализует параллельное выполнение запросов. Что бы в этом убедится достаточно в представлении сделать sleep и выполнить другой запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала ознакомьтесь с [главной страницей nginx](https://nginx.org/ru/).

Вы можете не использовать nginx и допустим воспользоваться gunicorn. Если посмотреть документацию к gunicorn, то в ней говорится, что без nginx, он подвержен атакам на отказ в обслуживании.

> Although there are many HTTP proxies available, we strongly advise that you use Nginx. If you choose another proxy server you need to make sure that it buffers slow clients when you use default Gunicorn workers. Without this buffering Gunicorn will be easily susceptible to denial-of-service attacks. You can use slowloris to check if your proxy is behaving properly.

Но, отдача статики тогда тоже должна быть с помощью django и это будет добавлять нагрузки на сервер.

К тому-же ваш "продуктив" сложно назвать продуктивом, если им пользуется 1 клиент. А если клиентов несколько, то можно экономить на серверах, используя nginx.